# How to create a popup/overlay upon highlighting words like Google Dictionary extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a in-window popup when some text is highlighted, similar to how the [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) extension works. I've already figured out how to do the highlighting portion, just can't figure out how to create the popup.

Here's the code for the highlighting:

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    console.log(text);
}

document.onmouseup = function() {getSelectionText()};
```

Comment: Simply add a div element to the page. Inspect any extension that does similar thing for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position popover over a highlighted portion of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246522/how-to-position-popover-over-a-highlighted-portion-of-text)